# Replace a character preceding a number using regex in R

Tags: regex, r

I have a number of column names that can be represented by the following pattern.

```
dat <- c("Male97","Male98","Male99", "Male100andover","Female0","Female1" ,"Female2", "Female3", "Female4" ,"Female5", "Female100andover")
```

I am trying add a preceding delimiting character e.g. a dash, between a letter and numeric characters using a regex.

My desired output is, for example, `Male-97`, or `Female-0`. However, I do not want the delimiting character inserted after the numeric characters in cases of '100 and over'.

I have tried the following regex:

```
gsub('([e])[0-9]', '-', dat)
```

It nearly works. I need something that does not substitute the 'e' with a dash.

Can someone help me along with this please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `([e])[0-9]` regex matches an captures `e` followed by a digit, even if the digit is not at the end of the string. Then, you only use `-` in the replacement, and thus the digit is lost. You could try to use another capturing group with `([0-9])`, but it would change the value in `Male100andover` and suchlike.

You can use a capturing group powered regex like this:

```
dat <- c("Male97","Male98","Male99", "Male100andover","Female0","Female1" ,"Female2", "Female3", "Female4" ,"Female5", "Female100andover")
gsub("(\\d+)$", "-\\1", dat)
```

See [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/uRCgSC).

Explanation:

- `(\\d+)` - matches and captures into Group 1 one or more digits that are...
- `$` - at the end of the string.

In the replacement pattern, `\1` backreferences the captured digits.

Result:

```
 [1] "Male-97"          "Male-98"          "Male-99"          "Male100andover"  
 [5] "Female-0"         "Female-1"         "Female-2"         "Female-3"        
 [9] "Female-4"         "Female-5"         "Female100andover"
```

**EDGE CASE HANDLING**:

```
gsub("(\\d+\\D*)$", "-\\1", dat) ## insert before the last digit sequence
## [1] "Male-97"             "Male-98over"         "Male99over-100under"
gsub("^(\\D*)(\\d+)", "\\1-\\2", dat) ## insert before the first digit sequence
## [1] "Male-97"             "Male-98over"         "Male-99over100under"
```

See [another demo](https://ideone.com/ENFqjl)

Comment: thanks, this is almost what I need, and it's a great explanation. As always, the edge cases are the problem. Do you know how to handle the `100andover` cases? I could do a two-step gsub and clean them up before I use your example. A one-step would be awesome though.

Comment: If you elliminate the `$` you will get results like this: `"Female-100andover"`.  Is this what you need?

Comment: Just a sec, does it mean `Female100andover` should be turned into `Female-100andover`? What about `Female100and200over`?

Comment: @stribizhev - first one to turn `Female100andover` into `Female-100andover`. The numbers represent ages. The additional examples will be very useful for other mungeing I need to do. Again, many thanks for showing me this.

Comment: Good, so the second edge case should work for you. And @R.Schifini's suggestion is for adding a `-` before all digit sequences in the input strings (remove the `$` in my first suggestion).